# $ f (x, y)=0$ ae in $ R^2$ implies there is $ a, b $ such that $ f (ta, tb)=0$ for almost every $ t \in R $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$ f: R^2 \to R $

$ f (x, y)=0$ ae in $ R^2$ implies there is $ a, b $ such that $ f (ta, tb)=0$ for almost every $ t \in R $

True or false ?

Comment: Could you solve the almost identical problem "... implies there is $a$ such that $f(x,a)=0$ for almost all $x\in\Bbb R$"?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think they are not almost identical

Comment: These two problems are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$0=\int_{\mathbb R^2} |f| = \int_0^\pi \left(\int_{\mathbb R} |f(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta))||r|dr \right)d\theta$$

so for almost all $\theta$ (and thus infinitely many), one has:

$$\int_{\mathbb R} |f(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta))||r|dr=0$$

Which means that for such $\theta$ and for almost all $r$:

$$ f(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta)) = 0$$

Comment: Nice so there is infinitely many pair $(a, b ) $